# MOT Power Increase

Tags: power, transformer, microwave

Your average mid level MOT can support around 1000 watts or 2000 volts at 0.5 amps. To quadruple the power of that, I need 4000 volts at 1 amp. Could you combine several MOTs or alter one's windings to get 4000 watts out of them at that voltage and current?

Answer (score 1):

MOTs are not 'ideal' transformers. One non-ideality is intentional, the others are just because they are intended for a very specific and cheap application.

- They have a low primary inductance, and operate well into saturation, so draw a very large magnetising current. Fortunately this magnetising current is in quadrature to the load current, so doesn't increase the on-load primary copper loss as much as you might think. However, it's not uncommon for a 1 kW MOT to draw 1 kVA when unloaded. A MOT is intended to operate with fan-cooling.
- They have a high leakage inductance. This is designed in, to improve the efficiency of the diode voltage doubler the MOT was designed to drive. For normal duty, the shunts that cause this can be knocked out (along with the heater winding turns) to give space to throw on a few extra primary turns to reduce the core saturation.

If you want to parallel MOTs, then if you've left the shunts in, it's fairly safe even if they are not well matched to each other. The high leakage inductance will mean that any mismatch circulating current will be small. If you've removed the shunts, you will need to use matched MOTs.

It's easy to double the output voltage if you're happy for the output voltage to be balanced about ground. Connect and ground the cores of two MOTs, connect the primaries in anti-parallel, and take your 4 kV from the two hots. If there's no voltage between the hots, reverse one of the primaries.

Comment: Thank you sir, very informative.

Answer (score 0):

MOTs are designed for intermittent, not continuous power. If you are planning to use the MOT continuously, you won't be able to use the transformer from a 1 kW oven for to get 1kW continuous power. It will overheat. If you want 4kW power you will need 5 or even 6 MOTs. Sorry for the bad news, but that's the way it is.

Also, MOTs have magnetic shunts. These increase the reactive power pulled by the transformer. If you don't need current limiting (as you might if you are using the MOT cores for welding transformers) you should remove the magnetic shunts.

Every transformer has a limit to the amount of magnetic flux its core can "hold". If the transformer is driven beyond that limit, it will draw excessive current, and will very likely overheat. MOTs are, as you may have guessed by now, designed right on the limit. (It saves cost and weight). Many people wind their own secondaries for MOTs. If you have the option, adding a few more turns in series with the primary will increase the inductance of the primary, lower the magnetization current, and lower the flux in the core. This can help to reduce core losses and heating. Adding 10% more turns to the primary is probably a good starting point. Of course, if you plan on keeping the windings as is, there is doubtlessly no room to add more turns.

Core saturation depends upon a number of factors, including the core material, its dimensions, primary turns, and the applied volt-seconds per cycle. For a fixed line frequency and line voltage, connecting MOTs in parallel will have zero impact on core saturation.

Comment: Ah, thank you. No bad news, only new information. Would connecting 5 or 6 MOTs effect core saturation? I read that can be a problem when dealing with MOTs, however, I am not entirely sure what it means.

Comment: Answer has been editted

Comment: Food for thought: you don't have an infinite amount of old microwave ovens just sitting around. The time, gasoline, and potentially junk yard money you pay to get 6 of them and combined them into something that works like an unregulated welding transformer - is it really cheaper than buying a used welder?

Comment: @mmmm Please excuse my ignorance in this area, but when you say unregulated what are you referring to? As I understand it, aren't welding transformers low voltage high current vs a MOT being "high voltage and high current"?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question? What do these facts about the transformers have to do with whether you can regulate things?

Comment: @mmmm I am curious to see how you could use a 1kW MOT to get 4kW, either through altering one MOT's winding or connecting multiple. With MOTs being so available I was just wondering how far you could stretch their function.